# Django Writing database migrations forward function issue

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, migration

I'm trying to add custom migration to django app. I want that the custom migration wouldn't work with "default" database and another custom migration works with only "default" database. I apply method suggested in django documentation but migration commands never worked. How can i fix this issue? Thanks for helps.

Django documentation page:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/writing-migrations/

My code (0001_initial.py,only works with "default" database):

```
from django.db import migrations, models

def forwards(apps, schema_editor):
    if schema_editor.connection.alias == 'default':
        migrations.CreateModel(
                name='Planets',
                fields=[
                    ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                    ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                    ('description', models.TextField(blank=True)),
                ],
            ),



class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards),
    ]
```

Other migration (only works with non "default" databases):

```
from django.db import migrations, models

def forwards(apps, schema_editor):

    if schema_editor.connection.alias != 'default':

        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='data_sources',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('sql_query', models.TextField(default='')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='query_history',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('query', models.TextField()),
                ('date', models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ],
        ),

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('universe','0001_initial')
    ]

    operations = [
         migrations.RunPython(forwards),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one days effort, I found a solution.  I don't use Django migration system for new dynamic databases anymore. Instead of this, I use Django SchemaEditor. create_model() method can automatically create database tables from any model.

SchemaEditor: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/schema-editor/

If you want to use SchemaEditor for non-default databases, you have to use connections module. For example:

```
from django.db import connections

with connections['connection_alias'].schema_editor() as schema_editor:

                schema_editor.create_model(any model)
```

On the other hand, If you don't want that django create migration from model, you have to set managed to False in model. For example:

```
class Objects(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       managed = False
```

Now, after

> manage.py makemigrations

command, django create migration file for this model (Don't worry) but it never creates any table in database for this model.